# Sending special character for a web-api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Hi all enthusiastics programmers.
I am making a get call from a C# client towards a web-api Project
The code looks like below

```
    private const string Url = "http://localhost:61809/";
    public ItemService()
    {

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }


public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(string searchString)
    {
        List<Items>  = null;
        string path = @"api/item/" + searchString;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Url+path).ConfigureAwait(false); 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            items = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Item>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Everything works but if a look after a item whcih contains the character # it fails. If i looks for the item i.e Mastering C# it fails. I have debugged this on the backend side also and the content on the backend doesn't contain the character #. The content is Mastering C which of course fails.
The same occurs if i sent the request from Postman
What can i do to get it works? Some special encoding or configuration of the backend code?

Comment: try using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to encode it. I'm in the process of writing [a library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/UniformResourceIdentifiers) that does this correctly, but it's not released yet.

In the meantime, you can use percent encoding as such:

```
public class UrlEncoding
{
  public static Encoding Utf8EncodingWithoutBom { get; } = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);

  public static string PercentEncodePathSegment(string value)
  {
    var bytes = Utf8EncodingWithoutBom.GetBytes(value);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length);
    foreach (var ch in bytes)
    {
      if (ch == '-' || ch == '.' || ch == '_' || ch == '~' ||
          (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') ||
          (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'Z') ||
          ch == '!' || ch == '$' || ch == '&' || ch == '\'' ||
          ch == '(' || ch == ')' || ch == '*' || ch == '+' ||
          ch == ',' || ch == ';' || ch == '=' ||
          ch == ':' || ch == '@')
      {
        sb.Append((char)ch);
      }
      else
      {
        sb.Append("%" + ch.ToString("X2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
      }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```